# Unicode String support in java and python

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, unicode

I have an Android application where I read sms messages and send it to the google app engine server. Some of the users are complaining that the certain languages are not coming through properly.

```
        // Execute query
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                SMS_PROVIDER_URI,
                SMS_QUERY_FIELDS,
                "date >= " + startDate.getTime(),  // selection - get messages > startDate
                null,                              // selectionArgs
                "date ASC");                       // order - get oldest messages first

        // Iterate results
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            // read through all the sms and create a list
            do {
                String sender              = cursor.getString(0);
                String message             = cursor.getString(2);
                boolean isIncomingMessage  = cursor.getString(3).contains("1");
                Date date                  = new Date(cursor.getLong(1));

                String contactName = ContactLookup.lookup(context, sender);

                smsList.add(new SMSMessageInfo(sender, contactName,
                        message, isIncomingMessage, date));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

message variable contains sms messages from different languages. How do I support it? 
Also, I need to send it to my server (python) and how do I translate the unicode on the sever?

Comment: Python works quite well with Unicode. Here is a comprehensive article: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7 there are two classes of string, `str` (the standard strings, consisting of bytes) and `unicode` (consisting of unicode characters, denoted as literal using the u prefix: u"foo").  Conversions are done by using methods on the instances:

```
u"blä".encode('utf8') → "bl\xc3\xa4"  # from unicode to str
"bl\xc3\xa4".decode('utf8') → u"blä"  # from str to unicode
```

Conversion often takes place implicitly, e. g. if you add a `str` to a `unicode`, the `str` gets promoted to a `unicode` (on default by using encoding `ascii`) prior to concatenation.

On the other hand, a `unicode` instance that gets `print`ed will be converted to a `str` first, using an encoding that depends on the stream it gets printed on (typically `ascii` as well).

These occasions of automatic conversion are often the source of exceptions (namely if conversion fails).  If you catch too many exceptions, these might go unnoticed, and then just some facility does not work.